# Issues setting cookie with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

I'm trying to write some jQuery that, when the page loads, checks to see if a cookie has been set. If it hasn't been set, a modal opens, and a cookie is set for 6 hours.

It seems as though my cookie is not getting set, and I don't get either of the console.log statements in my if/else statements, whether the cookie is set or not. In the console, when I type `$.cookie('email-signup')`, I get the error message "Cannot read property 'cookie' of undefined.

I've never really done this before, so any help or advice would be really appreciated!!!

My jQuery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   if (!!$.cookie('email-signup')) {
        SetNewsletterCookie(email);
        console.log('loaded');

    }

   function SetNewsletterCookie(email) {
      $('#modalnewslettercontent').html('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="400" src="'+themePath+'views/newsletter-signup.html"></iframe>');

         var date = new Date();
         var minutes = 180;
         date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
         $.cookie('email-signup', 1, {expires: date, path: '/'});
         console.log('cookie set');

    }   
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

According To Jquery-Cookie's [docs](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme), you'r `var` statement creats a variable and not a cookie. try again with their examples:

> Create session cookie:
>
> ```
> $.cookie('name', 'value');
> ```
>
> Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
>
> ```
> $.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
> ```
>
> Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:
>
> ```
> $.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the value you have to assign to your cookie.

> what you have now is `var newsletter = $.cookie('email-signup');`
>
> and it should be:  `var newsletter = $.cookie('email-signup', 1);`
>
> the "1" is your value.

to set your cookie to expire in 6 hours like your question, you can do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var newsletter = $.cookie('email-signup', 1);
  console.log(newsletter);
  if (newsletter == null) {
        SetNewsletterCookie('email-signup', 180);
  }

function SetNewsletterCookie(newsletter, minutes) {
$('#modalnewslettercontent').html('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="400" src="../../email-signup.html"></iframe>'); 
         var date = new Date();
         var m = minutes;
         date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
         $.cookie(newsletter, 1, { expires: date });
  } 
});
```

Comment: OK...I can see the cookie now. Is the 1 the expiration time, though?

Comment: No, the 1 is the value of the cookie. to set the expiration time you have to do something like this.

Comment: Ah, got it. OK, no I have something to set the expiration.

Comment: No, the 1 is the value of the cookie. to set the expiration time you have to do something like this.
`$.cookie('email-signup', 1, { expires: 1 });`
the `expires: 1` means: expires in  1 day. see : https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md

Comment: See my answer above for more.

Comment: Argh, this still isn't working! I have a console.log if it's not set, and one if it does get set, and I'm not hitting either!!

Comment: @bjorkland can you put it in a jsfiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You've written:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });
```

But the function `function($) { ... }` is called with no arguments. This means `$` inside the function definition (which is declared separately from the `$` declared outside) is `undefined`, even if the `$` on the outside is defined. (I don't know whether it is.) That function should just be `function() { ... }`, without the `$` argument; if you change that it might fix it. If not, replace all occurrences of `$` with `jQuery`, or else add `var $ = jQuery;`.